# Highcharts Sync charts horizontally

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to build a synchronous charts but aligned horizontally,  I did it based on

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

I made the alignment horizontal, now the charts are not synchronous

```js
/*
The purpose of this demo is to demonstrate how multiple charts on the same page can be linked
through DOM and Highcharts events and API methods. It takes a standard Highcharts config with a
small variation for each data set, and a mouse/touch event handler to bind the charts together.
*/

$(function () {

    /**
     * In order to synchronize tooltips and crosshairs, override the
     * built-in events with handlers defined on the parent element.
     */
    $('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
        var chart,
            point,
            i,
            event;

        for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
            chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
            event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
            point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

            if (point) {
                point.highlight(e);
            }
        }
    });
    /**
     * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
     */
    Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
        return undefined;
    };

    /**
     * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair
     */
    Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
        this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
        this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
    };

    /**
     * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
     */
    function syncExtremes(e) {
        var thisChart = this.chart;

        if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
            Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
                if (chart !== thisChart) {
                    if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
    // https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/activity.json
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity) {
        $.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {

            // Add X values
            dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
                return [activity.xData[j], val];
            });

            $('<div class="chart" style="width:200px;float:left;">')
                .appendTo('#container')
                .highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
                        spacingTop: 20,
                        spacingBottom: 20
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: dataset.name,
                        align: 'left',
                        margin: 0,
                        x: 30
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        crosshair: true,
                        events: {
                            setExtremes: syncExtremes
                        },
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value} km'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        positioner: function () {
                            return {
                                x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                                y: -1 // align to title
                            };
                        },
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'none',
                        pointFormat: '{point.y}',
                        headerFormat: '',
                        shadow: false,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        },
                        valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: dataset.data,
                        name: dataset.name,
                        type: dataset.type,
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
                        }
                    }]
                });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.chart {
    
}
</style>
<!-- http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Any help is much appricated,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could edit `event.chartX` after coordiantes are found in each chart by adding:

```
event.chartX = (event.chartX+600) % 200;
```

Adding `600` to avoid negative values and `%` by `200` because each chart has `200px` of width.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fzda6z8p/

Relevant part of code:

```
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart

        event.chartX = (event.chartX+600) % 200;

        point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point
        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice.. Thank you... :)

Comment: @kacper-madej, in my case charts are responsive; I have total 6 charts; two each row and for tablet / mobile devices one chart per row. I was able to access the chart's width via e.currentTarget.clientWidth, but what's the significance of '600' here?
What it should be in my case?
total number of charts each row * chart width?
or some thing else?

Comment: @kacper, 
I tried `(event.chartX + 2 * e.currentTarget.clientWidth) % e.currentTarget.clientWidth`
this seems to work but in some cases some charts are one point ahead or behind of the others? e.g. some are at the second point / index where as others are at the third.
is there any better approach you reckon?

Comment: @SaifUllah Please add a live demo. It might be easier to run you case in a new SO question then to exchange information in comments here.

Comment: @SaifUllah I am seeing the exact same issue as you - Did you find a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple series in each pair of charts. Sync fails when there are nulls in any of the series data.

This is a modified searchPoint function to find the exact category on X-Axis to be highlighted corresponding to the hovered point. So the crosshair moves smoothly even if there are blank values in the series.

```js
function searchPoint(event, chart) {
    var points = chart.series[0].points,
        len = points.length,
        x = chart.axes[0].toValue(event.chartX),
        range = 0.2,
        pointX,
        i;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        pointX = points[i].x;
        if (x - range < pointX && pointX < x + range) {
            return points[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Forum discussion: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=35903

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jj6a9jot/5/