# Highcharts Synchronized charts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Any way to get Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair by coordinate xData with chart layout in row, not in column?

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyFX/wt91mbvf/

Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37565667/4262914 based on static chart width:

```
 event.chartX = (event.chartX+600) % 200;
```

not good when:

```
.chart{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `searchPoint` searches for the **closest point** to the cursor. And actually it's done: the first point on the second chart is highlighted.

You can modify this a bit:

- set event on `.chart`, not on `#container`
- find hovered chart and retrieve the closest point
- use that point position as a fake event when searching corresponding points

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v2t171og/

Comment: That solution doesn't make sense for inverted charts.. In this solution, relation between points is taken from x-y position on the chart. This demo can demonstrate this better: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v2t171og/12/ - hover the first chart and check the red dot's position. You can try to scale the plotting position to find the nearest marker, or use `point.index` to find corresponding point on the other chart. Second solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v2t171og/13/ - note: number of points must match.