# Highcharts synchronize on xaxis value instead of pointer

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have a couple of synchronized charts in angular, but the problem im having is that the charts only synchronize when i put them exactly below eachother because the are synchronized through the pointer coordinates .(this also means that different size y-axis labels give an offset in xaxis value of the tooltip of each chart).

Is it possible to synchronize them through xaxis values?

I want it to be possible for my application to be scalable, but that will only be possible if i can correctly synchronize the charts.

Comment: The x- axis of all the chart have the same values

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. After a lot of headbanging the easiest solution for me was give both charts enough left margin to line up correctly `chart: {marginLeft: 75}`

Comment: This question has a few answers on SO. See these topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562048/highcharts-sync-charts-horizontally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037978/highcharts-synchronized-charts

Comment: @L3R5 Using your suggestion, mine now works. Thanks!