# Highcharts sync is not working horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have 6 charts in 2 rows with 3 bootstrap column grids. I am trying to sync all 6 charts but it is not working it works if my charts are in vertical position but I have to show these charts in 2 rows(horizontally).

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="container_1" style="height: 400px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="container_2" style="height: 400px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="container_3" style="height: 400px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="container_4" style="height: 400px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="container_5" style="height: 400px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="container_6" style="height: 400px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sync does not work horizontally. I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562048/highcharts-sync-charts-horizontally)

but in this we have to set chartX variable if I set this variable sync will work but this does not work correctly. I have seen in the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.PointerEventObject) for chartX but I am unable to understand what values should I set to work it properly

This is the link to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u93ynmr5/1/)
Please tell me how can I make these horizontal charts synchronous or what value should I set to make ChartX work properly because responsiveness is changing the width.

Thanks,

**PLEASE INCREASE WIDTH OF JSFIDDLE RESULT BOX TO SHOW CHARTS IN A ROW.**

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you have a gap between your charts. As the solution you can find which chart column is hovered and create an universal `event` variable:

```
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        if (chart && chart.options.chart.isSynced) {
            // Find coordinates within the chart
            event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent);

            if (event.chartX > 0 && event.chartX < chart.chartWidth) {
                Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(ch) {
                    point = ch.series[0].searchPoint(event, true);

                    if (point) {
                        point.highlight(e);
                    }
                });

                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pysx12kg/